# show comments of a post below the post in single.php wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have single.php file and I`m showing single post in it. I want to show comments on related to this post under this post. But the problem is I`m getting comments all of comments below any post.

Below is my single.php code

```
    <?php
/*
* The template for displaying all single posts and attachments
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="single_post_wrap">
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    <div class="time_and_author"><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?> by <?php the_author() ?></div>
    <div class="post_content"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
    <p>Posted in <?php the_category(', ') ?> | <?php comments_popup_link('No Comments »', '1 Comment »', '% Comments »'); ?></p>
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
        <?php  foreach (get_comments() as $comment): ?>
        <div><?php echo $comment->comment_author; ?> said: "<?php echo $comment->comment_content; ?>".</div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php comments_template(); ?>    
</div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Below is my comments.php code

```
<?php $comment_args = array(
        'comment_notes_after' => '',
        'title_reply' => 'Have something to say?'
    ) ?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

use [is_single()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_single) to check the post :

```
<?php if( is_single() ) : ?>

<?php  foreach (get_comments() as $comment): ?>
    <div><?php echo $comment->comment_author; ?> said: "<?php echo $comment->comment_content; ?>".</div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php comments_template(); ?>      

<?php endif; // close to check single.php ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `foreach` from **single.php**:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="single_post_wrap">
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    <div class="time_and_author"><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?> by <?php the_author() ?></div>
    <div class="post_content"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
    <p>Posted in <?php the_category(', ') ?> | <?php comments_popup_link('No Comments »', '1 Comment »', '% Comments »'); ?></p>
    <?php comments_template(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>    
</div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Then, add it to your **comments.php** and pass `$comment_args` in `get_comments()` like so:

```
<?php $comment_args = array(
        'comment_notes_after' => '',
        'title_reply' => 'Have something to say?'
      )
?> 
<?php foreach (get_comments($comment_args) as $comment): ?>
    <div>
        <?php echo $comment->comment_author; ?> said: "<?php echo $comment->comment_content; ?>".
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

have a look the the [function reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments) for `get_comments` to see the list of arguments you can pass into `get_comments`

Comment: Your edited code give this error. @Michael Doye


Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'endif' (T_ENDIF) in D:\wamp\www\wordpress-4.1.1\wordpress\wp-content\themes\plant_fusion2\single.php on line 17

Comment: Apologies, put it in the incorrect place!  have edited to the correct format.  Just needed to swap `endif;` and `endwhile;` @MaulikM.Dodia

Comment: Errors are gone but It shows all the comments instead of comments related to particular post. @Michael Doye

Comment: @MaulikM.Dodia there were a few things wrong there, I have made further to the answer.

Comment: @MaulikM.Dodia works fine for me, tested with Version 4.1.1  - returns comments for only that post

Comment: I have also Wordpress 4.1.1. But not getting result as expected. @Michael Doye

Answer (score 0):

**Single.php** code. Remove `get_comments()`

```
<?php
/*
* The template for displaying all single posts and attachments
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="single_post_wrap">
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    <div class="time_and_author"><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?> by <?php the_author() ?></div>
    <div class="post_content"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
    <p>Posted in <?php the_category(', ') ?> | <?php comments_popup_link('No Comments »', '1 Comment »', '% Comments »'); ?></p>
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
        <?php  foreach ($comments as $comment): ?>
        <div><?php echo $comment->comment_author; ?> said: "<?php echo $comment->comment_content; ?>".</div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php comments_template(); ?>    
</div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

You need to `get_the_ID()` per single page comment, then add **the comment query**.

```
$id - get_the_ID();
<?php $comment_args = array(
        'comment_notes_after' => '',
        'title_reply' => 'Have something to say?',
        'post__in' => $id, //Retrieves comments for an array of posts
        'post_id' => $post_ID // Post's ID you can make sure only comments related to that post appear.
      )
?> 
// The comment query
   $comments_query = new WP_Comment_Query;
   $comments = $comments_query->query( $args );
```